# Run Biztalk Health Monitor without sysadmin

Tags: sql-server-2012, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, bhm

Is there a way to run Biztalk Health Monitor without sysadmin role?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a conversation about this topic with one of Microsoft's BHM developers, Jean-Pierre Auconie.

He explained to me that the check for SYSADMIN is a new feature in BHM 4.1
The reason why they implemented this, is to avoid an inconsistent BHM report that has a lot of Access Denied errors in it (BHM uses a lot of interesing queries that require SYSADMIN rights).

BHM is a troubleshouting tool and this kind of tools are known to require some kind of elevated permissions as they normally are executed by administrators.

So, **in the current version of BHM 4.1 it is not possible to run the tool without SYSADMIN rights**.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are asking because some DBA type has raised this as an issue.

The correct response is to remind them that the BizTalk SQL Instances and Databases are part of the BizTalk Server Product and are exempt from any incompatible 'rules' they may impose.

In practice, I prefer to limit DBA access to the BizTalk databases rather then the other way around.